# How build a URL with UriComponentsBuilder where a parameter is a list of values

Tags: java, uri

I am trying to build a URI with UriComponentsBuilder, I have a parameter where the value is a list.

```
UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://example/endpoint")

                    .queryParam("client_id", clientId)
                    .queryParam("scope", list) //[scope1, scope2, scope3]
                    .queryParam("redirect_uri", redirectUri);

    return uriComponentsBuilder.build(false).encode().toUriString();
```

Output:

```
https://example/endpoint?client_id=clientId&scope=scope1&scope=scope2&scope=scope3&redirect_uri=https://redirect
```

This is not correct I have a scope parameter for each value of the list **scope=scope1&scope=scope2&scope=scope3**

The expected result should be:

```
 https://example/endpoint?client_id=clientId&scope=scope1+scope2+scope3&redirect_uri=https://redirect
```

What is the correct way to map list values to a parameter?

Comment: `String.join("+", list)` ?

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just do

```
.queryParam("scope", String.join("+",list))
```